# Can I return a return value from another function?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class like this:

```
class Example {

    private function _test($value)
    {
         if ($value == 'xyz') return FALSE;
    }

    public function check()
    {
        $this->_test('xyz');

        // more code follows here...
    }

}
```

Basically what I want to do is "bubble up" the return value FALSE from the method _test() as the actual return value of the method check(), so that calling

```
$this->_test('xyz');
```

will return FALSE

```
return $this->_test('xyz');
```

wouldn't work because I don't want to return if the value doesn't match 'xyz'.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand 100% what you're looking for, so if this isn't what you mean please explain a little more what you want.

```
public function check()
{
    if($this->_test('xyz') === FALSE){
         return FALSE;
    }

    // more code follows here...
}
```

Comment: i understand that i could do this. but i want to avoid the if clause in the check() method and instead inherit the return value from the _test method

Comment: If you *only* want to return if a certain condition is true, you have no choice but to use some sort of `if` construct.

Comment: then just do `$result = $this->_test('xyz')`? Can you explain what you expect to happen more clearly. What is your end goal with the check() function?